# SQLAlchemy import error : import _mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, pydev

I am new at Python and SQLAlchemy and I was trying to play with them a little bit, but whenever I run a test it gives me the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zakaria/workspace-python/Jerreb/essai/tejriba.py", line 11, in <module>
    engine = create_engine("mysql://root:root@localhost/python")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.7-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 346, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.7-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 74, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.9.7-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/sqlalchemy/connectors/mysqldb.py", line 64, in dbapi
    return __import__('MySQLdb')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/_mysql.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
```

I am working with PyDev.

This is the project architecture:

[image: Project Architecture]

And these are the libs I have imported :

[image: Project Libs]

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When I got this message, it turned out that, unbeknownst to me, the code was being run in the Python 3 interpreter, instead of Python 2. (This happened because I had installed Ubuntu's `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` for a different project.) `MySQL-python` does not yet support Python 3. :'(

I don't know whether WSGI is involved for you, but try making sure you're not running Python 3.